# Rails relationship between three models confusing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-models

I know there is a plenty of tutorials explaining how to create a 'has_many through' relationship between models, but I think my question is both technical and conceptual.

- The objective is to create an online food ordering website
- I created the Order, Item and OrderItem models.

Relationships:

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, conditions: "active = true"
  belongs_to :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :items, through: :order_items

  validates :status, inclusion: { in: %w(ordered completed cancelled) }    
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: :items_categories

  has_many :order_items
  has_many :orders, through: :order_items

  validates_presence_of :title, :description
  validates :price, numericality: { :greater_than=>0 }    
end
```

Am I doing something wrong? Each order should be able to contain many items and the quantity of them. 
I'm not very positive I'm doing the correct architecture for these models, as I can't assign the quantity via << operator, only assign the item.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: ¿? what is your command in the console? I dont see quantity attribute in OrderItem model

Comment: Dennis,  the quantity was set in the migration, there is a column with this name in the order_items table. How should I set the order items? I have a doubt in this matter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
order = Order.new(user: @user)
order.order_items << OrderItem.new(quantity: 100, item: Item.first)
```